# C++ Template function fails to compile with g++ when using namespace

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, namespaces, g++

The following code compiles just fine: **(Without namespace)**

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
void foo(const int & from, std::vector<T> & to)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        T bar;
        foo(from, bar);
        to.push_back(bar);
    }
}

struct Bar
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct Baz
{
    std::vector<Bar> bars;
};


void foo(const int & from, Bar & to)
{
    to.a = from;
    to.b = from - 1;
}

void foo(const int & from, Baz & to)
{
    foo(from, to.bars);
}

void fooTest()
{
    int num = 10;
    Baz baz;
    foo(num, baz);
}

int main()
{
    fooTest();
}
```

But when I introduce namespace for Bar and Baz, it fails to compile. **(With namespace)**

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
void foo(const int & from, std::vector<T> & to)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        T bar;
        foo(from, bar);
        to.push_back(bar);
    }
}

// When I add this namespace, it fails to compile
namespace BarBar
{
    struct Bar
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    };

    struct Baz
    {
        std::vector<Bar> bars;
    };
}


void foo(const int & from, BarBar::Bar & to)
{
    to.a = from;
    to.b = from - 1;
}

void foo(const int & from, BarBar::Baz & to)
{
    foo(from, to.bars);
}

void fooTest()
{
    int num = 10;
    BarBar::Baz baz;
    foo(num, baz);
}

int main()
{
    fooTest();
}
```

It shows error:

```
with_namespace.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void foo(const int&, std::vector<T>&) [with T = BarBar::Bar]’:
with_namespace.cpp:37:22:   required from here
with_namespace.cpp:9:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(const int&, BarBar::Bar&)’
         foo(from, bar);
            ^
with_namespace.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: template<class T> void foo(const int&, std::vector<T>&)
 void foo(const int & from, std::vector<T> & to)
      ^
with_namespace.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
with_namespace.cpp:9:12: note:   ‘BarBar::Bar’ is not derived from ‘std::vector<T>’
         foo(from, bar);
        ^
```

Also note that the code with namespace compiles just fine when using MSVC. Why can't the compiler find the definition when using namespace?

I am using following version: **g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609**

**UPDATE:**
After @M.M pointed out about how the function lookup works for templates and ADL, I went with the following fix:

```
#include <vector>



template <class T>
void foo(const int & from, std::vector<T> & to)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        T bar;
        foo(from, bar);
        to.push_back(bar);
    }
}

namespace BarBar
{
    struct Bar
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    };

    struct Baz
    {
        std::vector<Bar> bars;
    };
};


// Put them in the same namespace as Bar so that the templated foo find this function
namespace BarBar
{
    using ::foo; // We are going to use templated foo in the latter functions

    void foo(const int & from, BarBar::Bar & to)
    {
        to.a = from;
        to.b = from - 1;
    }

    void foo(const int & from, BarBar::Baz & to)
    {
        foo(from, to.bars);
    }

}

void fooTest()
{
    int num = 10;
    BarBar::Baz baz;
    BarBar::foo(num, baz);
}



int main()
{
    fooTest();
}
```

Comment: it compiles if you forward declare `namespace BarBar { class Bar; } void foo(const int & from, BarBar::Bar & to);` at the beginning.

Comment: Also compiles if you forward-declare the templated `foo` function and define it after the `BarBar` namespace.

Comment: Yes, I have checked that if the function is forward declared before the templated function then it compiles. But it is just a workaround. 
Shouldn't the templated function be able to compile with the namespace?
It rather seems to be a limitation of gcc to not be able to handle namespace in this case correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code:

```
template <class T>
void foo(const int & from, std::vector<T> & to)
{
    T bar;
    foo(from, bar);
```

the name `bar` is *type-dependent* because its type depends on a template parameter. Furthermore the name `foo` (in `foo(from, bar)`) is a *dependent name* because one of the function call arguments is type-dependent. (C++17 [temp.dep]/1).

Name lookup for dependent names works like this (C++17 [temp.dep.res]/1):

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:
>
> - Declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template.
> - Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context and from the definition context

The second bullet point is known as ADL  (argument-dependent lookup).

---

In your second code, looking up the dependent `foo` finds nothing:

- there is no other definition visible at the point of the template
- The associated namespaces of `int` and `T` (which is `BarBar::Bar`) are: `BarBar`, and there is no name `BarBar::foo`.

In the first code, looking up the dependent foo: the associated namespaces of `int` and `::Bar` are: the global namespace.  There is `::foo` in the global namespace, so that is found by ADL.

To fix the second code you should move the later definitions of `foo` which take a `BarBar::` argument, to be inside `namespace BarBar`. (You will also need a `using ::foo` at line 37 to find the template foo in this case).

Comment: @m-m thanks for pointing out about ADL.
So, templated foo does not look for definitions of foo inside its declaring namespace i.e the global namespace.


If we had templated foo inside FooFoo namespace and latter foo functions inside the same namespace FooFoo too, then it wouldn't find the latter foo's. Surprising!


Shouldn't the templated foo also look for foo in it's declaring namespace foo too? 


I think MSVC does that. Which is why the 2nd code compiled fine with MSVC.

Comment: @ZulkarnineMahmud MSVC does not implement name lookup correctly.  The innermost enclosing namespace of template foo is not part of the ADL set. The non-ADL part of name lookup there works the same as for any other name; declarations that are not visible at that point are not found. It is the same error as `void f() { g(); }   void g() {}`  . The compilation of `f` does not look forwards to find a `g` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your templated `foo()`:

```
foo(from, bar);
       // ^^^ error
```

The point of declaration for all names inside a namespace starts from the namespace specifier id.

The error is due to the fact that `BarBar::Bar` was not yet defined **before** your templated foo function.

That's why a forward-declaration solves the issue.

Comment: If that was the case then why would the first example without the namespace compile?

Comment: Also please note that if you just change the namespace to struct then the latter code compiles just fine. 
So, I don't think it is an issue with the scope. It rather seems to be a bug in gcc while interpreting namespaces.

Comment: @ZulkarnineMahmud, it's basically just the rules of the name look-up.

Comment: you are right that forward declaring the class and function will solve the issue but that is not mandatory. M.M pointed this out more clearly about how this lookup works. So, this issue can be solved without forward declaring the classes and functions and putting them in appropriate namespaces.